# polynomials in linear vector spaces (question about inequalities)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I came across the followng definition in a textbook:

$\textbf{k}_n[x]$ is a subspace of $\textbf{k}_m[x]$ under m $\ge$ n, and also of $\textbf{k}[x]$

I get how $\textbf{k}_n[x]$ can be a subset of $\textbf{k}_n[x]$ (or a proper subset rather), but how can a set of all polynomials with degree 3 for e.g. be a subset of all polynomials with degree 1 (referring to "and also of $\textbf{k}[x]$")? Unless spaces and sets have different definitions in this regard, or I'm misunderstanding the statement.

Comment: $\textbf{k}[x]$ is the set of all polynomials, all degrees, or at least it is very likely that that is the notation used by your source.

Comment: @user85667 Thank you! One more question - would $\textbf{k}[x]$ then include infinite degrees (If such a thing even exists)? And if it not, then what would be the difference between $\textbf{k}_n[x]$ and $\textbf{k}[x]$ ?

Comment: No, $\mathbf{k}[x]$ is only polynomials, all coefficients, except for finitely many are zero. There is the ring of formal power series (the coefficients for the terms of each non-negative degree can be any element from $\mathbf{k}$), which is commonly denoted by $\mathbf{k}[[x]]$. There is $\mathbf{k}\{\{x\}\}$, the formal Laurent series (any elements of $\mathbf{k}$ for coefficients of the terms of integer degrees, but only finitely many of the negative degrees are allowed to be non-zero).

Comment: @user85667 Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

k[x] is the set of all polynomials, all degrees, or at least it is very likely that that is the notation used by your source.

Answered by @user85667

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).